# Generating sample non-picked values using negative subscripting in R?

Tags: r, subscript

Stats student here.  I've been tasked with combining 2 sets of values and then combining them for the purposes of doing permutations tests.  In this example I combine the vectors into one, then use the sample() function to pull out half the values to find their mean and compare it to the other half.  I've been told that I can use negative subscripting to somehow pull the non-picked values and put them into another variable so I can compare the means.

```
controls <- c(6.33, 1.65, -3.58, 3.3, -6.6, 3.29, 1.80, 1.80, 2.98) ## group 1
redA <- c(6.84, -9.83, -0.02, -9.12, -0.07, -19.34, 3.97, -16.37, -21.02) ## group 2
allscores <- c(controls, redA) ## combine vectors
allscores ## check new vector
controlIDs <- sample(allscores,9) ## pull out 9 random values
otherIDs <- allscores[-controlIDs] ## get other 9 non-picked values
difference <- mean(controlIDs) - mean(otherIDs) ## compare means
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Error in allscores[-controlIDs] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Conceptually I've had a hard time figuring our how R is able to pick out the non-picked sample values using a negative subscript when I thought sample is run independently.

Can someone tell me if I've got the code somehow mixed up here?  Ideally this will work so it can be put into a for loop and run a bunch of times to create a distribution of the values.  Would appreciate any help in learning how to use the negative subscript to pull out the non-selected values into a separate vector.  A class call says the entire allscores vector is numeric, so I don't believe it's a conflict in the data types, but I could be wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error comes that you sampled values from `allscores` while you need indices of the values to remove them.

So you can use instead:

```
...
idx <- sample(seq_along(allscores),9) ## take 9 random values
controlIDs <- allscores[idx] ## pull out these 9random values
otherIDs <- allscores[-idx] ## get other 9 non-picked values
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.  However, when I run this it seems to give me the index #s for the values and not the values themselves.  IE
> controlIDs <- sample(seq_along(allscores),9)
> controlIDs
[1]  2  8  9 10  3 14 13 16 17
> mean(controlIDs)
[1] 10.22222
Any guidance on getting the means instead of the indexes?

Comment: ***
I've managed to figure it out.  I just created a new variable minus the negative subscript and it gave me the other values.  Thanks for your help! :) **
controlIDs <- sample(seq_along(allscores),9)
elseIDs <- allscores[-controlIDs]
controlyes <-allscores[controlIDs]
It's messy, but it'll do for what I need.